# Correct way to compare regression models where dependent variable is euclidean distance

Tags: regression, aic, euclidean

I am working on a psycholinguistics problem. I am modelling the response of perceived "goodness" (as assessed by human listeners providing their judgements on a 1-5 scale) of different collections of parameters that describe speech sounds. These parameters were varied systematically to produce artificial speech stimuli. Theoretically, perceptual "distance" from an optimum pronunciation should predict the goodness rating; which components human listeners are sensitive to, so which are good candidates to include in the perceptual   distance is what I am trying to test. So I calculate lots of linear regression models including different combinations of the potentially predictive parameters, to see which is most informative about the parameters that humans are sensitive to when evaluating the goodness of speech sounds of this type.

The "distance" of each item is calculated as the euclidean distance from the centre "optimum" item. So there is always only one dependent variable in each model, the euclidean distance, but that distance is composed of the varying combinations of parameters, which are shared by the other models I am comparing against.

So, is it valid to compare the quality of the fit of these models by directly comparing the R$^2$ or AIC in this case? (These come out as perfectly correlated, presumably because as far as AIC is concerned, there is only one dependent variable in each case).

Many thanks!

Comment: You may have the problem that "beauty is in the eye of the beholder".  Can you cluster the users response into clean "modes"?  Then you could look at a "most beautiful sound" for each mode.

Comment: @EngrStudent, thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure I really follow your thinking. Do you mean to cluster to find groups of raters that behave similarly? The whole group are actually fairly consistent (cronbach's alpha = 0.75). In linguistics that's considered pretty safe to assume the scale is valid and that evaluators are using the same strategy to assign ratings, and the noise is an artefact of the test methodology (lapses in concentration etc, drifting to the extremes as they evaluate more items.)